# Unable to get valid pointers from std::map of pointers to Polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have been struggling with a segmentation fault when trying to implement a container (map) for a set of Polymorphic classes, and `boost::ptr_map` seems one possible solution to have the memory properly managed, but before changing the implementation, I'd like to understand what am I doing wrong.

Suppose I have the following abstract class and two derived ones:

```
class Base {

 public:

    virtual ~Base() {};

    virtual void getClassName() = 0;

}

class Derived1 : public Base {

 public:

     void getClassName() { std::cout << "Derived1\n";}
}

class Derived2 : public Base {

 public:

     void getClassName() { std::cout << "Derived2\n";}
}
```

And now suppose we have these two versions of a container for these classes. I anticipate that one fails when trying to de-reference the pointers (`ContainerSegFault`) and the other seems to do the proper thing (`ContainerOk`):

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Base *> PointerMap;


class ContainerSegFault {

 public:

     void loadDerived1(){

         dataDerived1.push_back(Derived1());

         data.insert(std::make_pair("derived1_A", &dataDerived1.back()));

     };

     Base* getPointer(const std::string& key) {

         return data[key];
     }

     PointerMap data;

     std::vector<Derived1> dataDerived1;
     std::vector<Derived2> dataDerived2;
}

class ContainerOk {

 public:

     void loadDerived1(){

         data.insert(std::make_pair("derived1_A", static_cast<Base *>(new Derived1())));

     };

     Base* getPointer(const std::string& key) {

         return data[key];
     }

     PointerMap data;

}
```

If I try to dereference the pointer in `ContainerSegFault`, like so:

```
ContainerSegFault containerFail;
containerFail.loadDerived1();
Derived1* pDerived1 = static_cast<Derived *>containerFail.getPointer("derived1_A");
pDerived1->getClassName();
```

I've got a Segmentation Fault (i.e. I always seem to get uninitialized pointers from the call to the `std::map::operator[]`). This error seems to go away if I use the class `ContainerOk`, like so:

```
ContainerOk container;
container.loadDerived1();
Derived1* pDerived1 = static_cast<Derived *>container.getPointer("derived1_A");
pDerived1->getClassName(); // Works ok
```

My understanding was that, in `ContainerSegFault`, I was safely allocating memory
when the object constructor was called in the `std::vector<Derived1>::push_back` 
method, but obviously this is not the case. So my question now is, what is
the essential difference between using the default constructor (and then storing the pointer to the last position of the vector) and the `new` operator? And, in the case of `ContaierOk`, where are the objects actually stored?

Any clarification in this issue will be greatly appreciated

@Tryskele

Comment: This is obviously not real code since there are several missing semicolons and this - `ContainerSegFault containerFail();` - is a function declaration. My guess is, in your real code, you're calling `push_back` on the `vector` several times, and loading the pointer into the `map` after each call. `vector::push_back` invalidates all pointers and references to existing elements.

Comment: Yes, you are right Praetorian, this is a simplified code for illustration. Ok, I missed the point of `std::vector` pointer invalidation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` would invalidate iterators of the `vector` if it needs to increase capacity. Thus, using `&dataDerived1.back()` is not a good idea - the address could change. If you need to work with pointers, make `PointerMap` a `map<string, unique_ptr<Base>>` and change `Derived1` and `Derived2` to be `vector`s of `unique_ptr`s.